# How to fetch posts with pagination feature in WP on a custom table?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a custom table that I created named `cars_plugin` and it has columns `id`, `name`, `color`, `model`

Now, I can get list of cars using

```
$sql = "SELECT note FROM cars_plugin WHERE ID = '$id'"; 
$query = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A); 
foreach($query as $car){
   // list cars here
}
```

The above code works as planned, and I could create a pagination for that, although it will be difficult, now my question is, if I have a custom table like that how do I query the table so I can be able to use the built-in Wordpress pagination functions?

Answer (score 1):

**This can't be done I think**

I found no way to use ***WordPress*** default pagination for custom table. Cause the default pagination is initiated in `WP_Query` class which is curated or built or written only for querying posts from `{wp-table-prefix}_posts` table and may be joining other table related to posts.

**So what is the solution ???**

May be you can create your own class which will return you the result with pagination and this could be by extending `WP_Query` class. But this method will need a lot of modifications to manipulate the base class default methods. So I would prefer writing a separate new class for this than extending the `WP_Query`.

Another way would be straight **PHP** method. You can chunk the queried result and show them page by page. And I think it would be the easiest and smart way to do pagination for custom table in ***WordPress***. For finding more on this method you can check those below links-

1. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53194/wordpress-paginate-wpdb-get-results
2. http://www.walkswithme.net/wordpress-pagination-for-custom-tables

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I already began making a pagination script with plain php since I arrived at the same conclusion as yours. I will wait to see if someone has other solution before I accept this answer